# Convolution and approximate heat kernel

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, heat-equation, integral-kernel

I have the following question: Let $A, B\in C^\infty((0,\infty)\times M\times M)$, where $M$ is a compact manifold. Define
\begin{align}
(A*B)(t,x,y) = \int_0^t\int_M A(t-s,x,z)B(s,z,y)dzds
\end{align}
For this to make sense a sufficient condition is that actually $A, B\in C^\infty([0,\infty)\times M\times M)$. Suppose furthermore that $A(0,x,y) = \delta(x-y)$. Then the following holds
\begin{align}
(\partial_t-\Delta_x)(A*B)(t,x,y) = B(t,x,y) + ((\partial_t-\Delta_x)A*B)(t,x,y).
\end{align}
See for example Isaac Chavel: Eigenvalues in Riemannian Geometry, page 153, Lemma 2. My questions is: Could this identity hold without assuming continuity up to $t=0$, but instead integrability? For example if we assume that $A(t,x,y) = (4\pi t)^{-n/2}e^{-d^2(x,y)/4t}$ and $B$ is integrable, could this identity still hold?

Comment: The initial condition for $A$ is not $C^\infty$ near $\{0\}\times\Delta M$. Also, do want $B$ integrable on $[0,\infty)\times M^2$ and $C^\infty$ for $t>0$?

Comment: $A$ has a singularity on the diagonal at $t=0$. But for $t>0$ it is smooth. Concerning $B$ it is as you say. If you need some further information, I want it near the diagonal, to be a smooth function up to $t=0$ times the factor $t^{-n/2 -b}$ for $b<1/2$, and near the diagonal to be a 'smooth' function of $d/\sqrt{t}$. The general case is that it is integrable on $[0,\infty)\times M\times M$.